# ecryptfs: ls lists top level folders but with "no such file or directory" for them

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, mount, ecryptfs

I've managed to mount "old" ecryptfs home folder with `sudo mount -t ecryptfs [SRC DIR] [DST DIR]`. It was failing for `ecryptfs-recover-private` with `mount: No such file or directory` and with `setreuid: Operation not permitted` for `strace --follow-forks -o file.log ecryptfs-recover-private`. BTW, why different error for `--follow-forks`? Maybe worth separate question about `strace`.

Anyway it mounted but `ls [DST DIR]` lists files and folders that look as correct home folder, but with `?` and "cannot access ... no such file or directory". What could be the problem?

With web search I've managed to find QAs for `mount` issue. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074753/ecryptfs-mount-private-failure-in-ubuntu-18-04-mount-no-such-file-or-directory; https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126981/ecryptfs-mount-no-such-file-or-directory; [mount: No such file or directory with encrypted recovery](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285541/mount-no-such-file-or-directory-with-encrypted-recovery;) ["ecryptfs-mount-private" returns "fopen: No such file or directory"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493931/ecryptfs-mount-private-returns-fopen-no-such-file-or-directory)

Closest to mine is [ecryptfs mounting failure from kernel 4.7 onwards](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314255/ecryptfs-mounting-failure-from-kernel-4-7-onwards) with also `?` for `ls`, but it is from 2016 and answer is for kernel change for plaintext+encrypted names change, my encrypted home folder is from 2021.

BTW I've tried `mount` both `plaintext passthrough` `y` and `n`.

Answer (score 1):

FDEK (filenames decryption key) offered by `mount` as default was not correct one and I have not noted that before.

*TL;DR*

I was able to mount and read my encrypted folder via `ecryptfs-recover-private`.

`ecryptfs-recover-private` is shell script that near the end has `mount -i -t ecryptfs -o "$mount_opts" "$d" "$tmpdir"`. I've compared my way to the script and the only IMO difference is `-i` flag in the script (other options looks like same as I've chosen interactively when I ran `mount -t ecryptfs`: `ecryptfs_sig=$mount_sig,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=$fnek_sig,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16`).

Knowing that, and thinking about the issue I've somehow realized to check FDEK and indeed in my terminal I saw FDEK (filenames decryption key) offered by `mount` as default was not correct one. After I entered second line from `Private.sig` as FDEK to `mount -t` it worked too.